# How can I make a UIPickerView like a UIDatePicker?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uipickerview

I have a custom UIViewController subclass which acts as Datasource and Delegate for a UIPickerView which I would like to serve two different purposes, as each are simple enough, and don't really warrant separate files. One operation must be as a custom picker, and this works fine. However, for the other operation, I want it to act just like a UIDatePicker.

The problem is, UIDatePicker is a subclass of UIControl, not UIPickerView. Is there any sort of enum value I can set in a method (or other way) that will set the UIPickerView to act as a date picker? Or do I have to make two completely different classes and use them differently (pain in the ass)?

Comment: What is custom about your picker, the appearance or the behaviour?

Comment: Oops, my bad, its actually a UIViewController subclass. Will edit. But it is the datasource and delegate of the UIPickerView.

Comment: Do you want to  USE TWO PICKER CONTROLLERS IN ONE CLASS?

Comment: Calm down. I want one class to change the type of picker depending on how I initialise it. Is that so bad? But I'll probably end up doing @jrturton's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be far simpler just to have a UIPicker and a UIDatePicker, and just hide the one you don't need. UIDatePicker has all sorts of complexities for handling international date formats and calendars which you don't want to reinvent.

Comment: How do I do this though? A UIPickerView is a view, and operates totally differently to a control. Or is there a way to set the picker in the view to a UIDatePicker?

Comment: Not really. A UIControl is a subclass of UIView, so you can hide or move them as you like.

Comment: Oh. Do the delegate, datasource etc. methods work the same for date picker as picker view?

Comment: No. You don't implement them for date picker - that's why it's not a UIPicker subclass. It is a control object that has a picker view as a subview, and implements the datasource methods internally. It does have valueChanged events and you can read and write the date value.

Comment: Of course. Der. Because it manages its own datasource and stuff to make dates.

Comment: This helped me, set UIDatePicker as the view for the TextInput.